# Finding tension in a freely sliding ring on a wire

Tags: dynamical-systems

A heavy small ring of weight $W$ is free to slide on a smooth surface wire of radius $a$, fixed in a vertical plane. It is attached by a string of length $l$ where

$$2a > l > a\sqrt{2}$$

to a point on the wire in a horizontal line with the centre. 
Find tension in the string.

**Approach :**

**1.** [image]

Here, If A be the point where string is attached to wire, P be the equilibrium position of string, I get Tension as

$$ \dfrac{W(l^2-2a^2)}{a\sqrt{4a^2-l^2}}$$
**2.** [image]

Here, If A be the point where string is attached to wire, P be the equilibrium position of string, I get Tension as

$$ \dfrac{- W(l^2-2a^2)}{a\sqrt{4a^2-l^2}}$$

Clearly, 2nd Approach is wrong as magnitude of tension can't be negative. But why is it wrong ? Why isn't this diagram possible ?

I have verified that with given restriction on $l$, the 2nd diagram should very well be possible. Can anyone point out where am I going wrong ?
Thanks!

Comment: Move to Physics?

Comment: I had it under Maths topic. So posted here. Can you direct to the link ? Thanks!

Comment: Direct to what link?

Comment: I thought you were mentioning about some link. I am sorry.

Comment: Did you use the same local coordinate system for $P$ in both cases? If so, your answer may be correct because the two tensions are in the opposite directions.

Comment: @JohnDouma Since I have already considered tension with directions, it shouldn't come out to be -ive.

Comment: In the first case, $T$ and $W$ are pointing downward while in the second case $W$ points downward while $T$ points upward.

Comment: Yeah, That's my question. Why can't the second case be possible ? Given the restrictions on l, it is very much possible. But you can say after solving, that it isn't. But can we do without solving, just by testing some conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering first the first position

By geometric considerations the angle $\angle PAB = \alpha $ is such that

$$
2 a \cos\alpha = l
$$

Now calling

$$
\vec R = r(\cos(2\alpha),\sin(2\alpha))\\
\vec W = w(0,-1)\\
\vec T =- t(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)
$$

in equilibrium we have

$$
\vec R + \vec W + \vec T = 0
$$

or

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 r \cos (2 \alpha )-t \cos (\alpha )& = & 0 \\
 -w-t \sin (\alpha )+r \sin (2 \alpha )& = & 0 \\
 2 a \cos (\alpha )& = & l \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving for $r,t,\alpha$ we obtain

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
t & r & \alpha \\
 \frac{\left(2 a^2-l^2\right) w}{a \sqrt{4 a^2-l^2}} & -\frac{l w}{\sqrt{4 a^2-l^2}} & \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{l}{a},-\frac{\sqrt{4
   a^2-l^2}}{a}\right) \\
 \frac{\left(l^2-2 a^2\right) w}{a \sqrt{4 a^2-l^2}} & \frac{l w}{\sqrt{4 a^2-l^2}} & \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{l}{a},\frac{\sqrt{4 a^2-l^2}}{a}\right)
   \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

one of them is discarded.

in the second position, the string can not remain taut.